# Keep dual-monitor settings in Windows 8.1 after closing laptop lid

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, power-management

I've got a Dell XPS 15 laptop connected to a (rather old) Dell 2408WFP monitor via HDMI. I want to use only the monitor when I'm at my desk, so I've set Windows to show the desktop there and switch the laptop display off.

This works fine on rebooting, but if I hibernate the laptop by closing the lid, Windows forgets my settings. On waking up it either duplicates the desktop on both screens, or it extends them, depending on what my setup was before I changed things. How do I get it to remember my settings after hibernating?

The laptop has double GPUs, both the Intel integrated GPU and an Nvidia GTX 750M, if that makes a difference.

---

EDIT: the problem appears to be specific to closing the lid. If I press the power button, then everything works as it should whether I set it to sleep or hibernate. Conversely, if I close the lid, then it always reactivates the laptop display on waking up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly no expert on windows 8 however from my experience on windows 7/vista/xp laptops, macbooks and chromebooks I'm pretty sure you may want to checkout if there's a "clamshell" type mode or setting on your laptop/in windows. This link is from vista but the power/battery settings are still in the control panel as specified, snoop around there and you may find something.
 Good luck!

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-vista/change-what-happens-when-you-close-your-mobile-pc-lid